# Google Cloud Functions list.operations parameters are unclear

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, operation

I'm trying to fetch all operations related my google Cloud Functions. I need to give a filter parameter for this, but it is unclear to me what this filter should actually be.

The filter is described as "standard list filter", but I couldn't find what this was referring to. From the documentation it was impossible for me to discern what the correct parameters could be.

EDIT:

So far I've tried getting it to work in the ["try this API" that's in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/list).

I've tried filters like

```
/operations/*
.*
*
```

and names such as

```
/v1/name/operations
/name/operations
*
```

The problem I'm having is that I just have no clue what a valid filter could look like, and as far as I can see it's not in the documentation other than "standard list filter".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/list#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.filter) now contains some explanations:

> The supported formats of filter are:
>
> - To query for specific function:
>
>   `project:*,location:*,function:*`
> - To query for all of the latest operations for a project:
>
>   `project:*,latest:true`